# How to get ride of infinite recursion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a OAuth2.0 Json data from client. And i have to pull all data from particular API to my SQL Database. this API having some validation like they can only show 250 data at one time and for next we have run API again with different parameter. 
strucutre of API data like this.

```
{
  "next": URL or null,                  // URL of the next page (same as the requested URL, but with the page query parameter incremented)
  "previous": URL or null,              // URL of the previous page
  "results": array of result objects    // the results follow the same format as `:endpoint/:id`
}
```

for next or previous data we have to run previous or  next in which URL Comes.

i make the automation to import the data from this API to  my SQL Data. But after some loops i got this error.[image]

And after this  rest of the data i can't import into my SQL database.
I am working on Dr.chrono API  to import their data into my system.
i don't understand what to do with this type of condition.

Below the code:-

```
private void recursivemethod(List<string> lstarray, String token, string URL, string flag, StringBuilder sb)
        {


                RestClient client = new RestClient(URL);

                RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.Parameters.Clear();
                client.Timeout = -1;
                request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                ////Using dynamic keyword with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, here you need to import Newtonsoft.Json  


                dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                if (flag == "patient")
                {
                    PatientMain items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PatientMain>(response.Content);
                    int i = 0;
                    lstarray.Clear();
                    foreach (var type in items.results)
                    {
                        i++;

                        lstarray.Add("INSERT INTO drchrono_patient(id,chart_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,date_of_birth,gender,social_security_number,race,ethnicity,preferred_language,patient_status,home_phone,cell_phone,office_phone,email,address,city,state,zip_code,doctor,primary_care_physician,date_of_first_appointment,date_of_last_appointment,default_pharmacy,referring_source,copay,updated_at) VALUES ('" + convertQuotes(type.id) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.chart_id) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.first_name) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.middle_name) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.last_name) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.date_of_birth) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.gender) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.social_security_number) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.race) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.ethnicity) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.preferred_language) + "' ,'" + convertQuotes(type.patient_status) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.home_phone) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.cell_phone) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.office_phone) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.email) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.address) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.city) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.state) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.zip_code) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.doctor) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.primary_care_physician) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.date_of_first_appointment) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.date_of_last_appointment) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.default_pharmacy) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.referring_source) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.copay) + "','" + convertQuotes(type.updated_at) + "') ");


                    }
                    string result = dbf.pExecuteQueryList(lstarray);
                    if (items.next != null)
                    {
                        URL = items.next;
                        recursivemethod(lstarray, token, URL, flag, sb);
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Please, share the entire code

Comment: Presumably you have an infinite recursion somewhere in your logic.  Does the exception have a stack trace?  That would identify the path of the recursion.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski please check my code.

Comment: @David But i don't know how much data is in API. I have to import all data using thru API. and they don't have any other resource.If i do manually it doesn't make any sense. but when i do automation then it show exception. I know i can't run infinite loop & recursion. but for this what can i do to get all data.

Comment: @Fildor Reason of using recursion is API provides only 250 data at one time. for next data they gives API URL in next & previous  as you can see above. if you have some idea please suggest and drop here.

Comment: @rks_dotnet: If this method you're showing is what's throwing the error then it's time to do some debugging.  Place a breakpoint in the method and observe each recursive call.  Are the parameters to the method changing as expected?  What condition is supposed to end the recursion?  Why is that condition not met?

Comment: @rks_dotnet That's no excuse to use recursion ;) I'll drop an answer later, busy right now.

Comment: @David as i mention in my code, if i got URL null then my recursion stop. But i don't know how much data are there. if i tell you i run approx 76 loop with 250 data after this i got exception , and using POSTMAN i can see there is much more data is coming from this API.

Comment: David nailed it already, I would only add insignificant (for the sake of the question) changes regarding code quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a loop instead of recursion.  You can keep much of your logic the same and just restructure how you're repeating it.  Let's start by changing the method signature to return a value.  Something like this should work:

```
private string GetItems(List<string> lstarray, String token, string URL, string flag, StringBuilder sb)
```

And within that method, instead of recursing back on itself, return that URL value:

```
foreach (var type in items.results)
{
    // your current loop, though be aware that you should update this to use query parameters
}
return item.next;
```

(Elsewhere in the method you can `return null;` by default so that all code paths return a value.)

Then conceptually your loop can look something like this:

```
var url = "whatever your initial starting URL is";
while (url != null)
{
    url = GetItems(lstarray, token, url, flag, sb);
}
```

Basically, recursion isn't really necessary here.  You're repeating an action an unknown number of times, but that unknown dynamic value can still be used as a loop condition and doesn't need to be recursive.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I think `sb` isn't even used in the original code?

Comment: @Fildor: Looks that way indeed.  I bet there are a number of other minor improvements that can be made.  I don't even fully like the idea of modifying the `lstarray` argument or a method that sometimes returns `null` as a magic value, but the fact that it's `private` at least assures me that this messiness is encapsulated.  Logically this should at least be a good start though.

Comment: Completely agreed.

Comment: @David - Thanks it's working. learn new things today. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a [`StackOverflow` exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=netframework-4.8). From the microsoft documentation:

> The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls.

Later in the documentation

> [...] typically in case **of a very deep** or unbounded recursion [..]

In fact your stopping condition is probably working fine, it is simply never reached before the [execution stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (the amount of memory your application has to run) is full.

Normally, when application are run, every variable, data structure, object that is not going to be used again is removed from the memory and it can be used to store something else.

The problem with recursion is that the memory cannot be emptied nor optimized until the recursion is completed, your memory fills up and at some point you run out.

I'm not sure recursion is a good choice here, you could simply do a loop which would be much more memory efficient, allowing the system to clean the memory between each itteration.

If you need to stick with recursion, you should consider re-modeling your code to pass all the variables as [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) otherwise the execution stack will fill up with a ton of useless replicated data that you do not need to be replicated.

Comment: _"I'm not sure recursion is a good choice here"_ if you have the slightest doubt it is the best choice, it isn't. (From experience and in production code) In academic settings, that may be different, though.

Comment: The rule we use at work is: If it's a lightweight tree structure (such as menus, file pointers trees, etc...) we go for recursion otherwise we don't use recursion.

Comment: in those cases you are sure, right?  